# How to store one value at a time with cin?

Tags: c++, validation, input, user-input

I am trying to assign a value to multiple `double` variables and I am using `std::cin`. But if the user uses space, it skips a variable.

How it should be:

```
Please enter the value for var1: 1 [Space] 2 [Space] 3
Please enter one variable at a time.
Please enter the value for var1: 1 [Enter]
Please enter the value for var2: 2 [Enter]
Please enter the value for var3: 3 [Enter]

You have entered the values, 1, 2 and 3 for var1, var2 and var3.
```

What it's doing right now:

```
Please enter the value for var1: 1 [Space] 2 [Space] 3
Please enter the value for var2:
Please enter the value for var3:

You have entered the values, 1, 2 and 3 for var1, var2 and var3.
```

I know it has to do with the `std::cin` keeping the values in the input stream, but how do I make it only accept one value at a time?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't use it, I thought it would be pretty self explanatory by just looking at the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::getline` to read the whole line and then parse that with `std::istringstream` or [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

`std::istringstream` version would be something like (not tested):

```
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
double value;

if(!(iss >> value))
{
    iss.clear();
    // invalid value
}
else if(iss.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)
{
    // there are more characters in the stream
}
```

If you don't want to give any feedback to the user, you can just do (without `std::getline`):

```
if(!(std::cin >> value))
{
    std::cin.clear();
    // invalid value
}

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Thanks @LogicStuff, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. I took your code and changed it a bit, this part helped me a lot `else if(iss.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)` I didn't know I could do that. I am reading through the reference text to better understand the 2 functions, but I don't really get what the `->` operator means? Is that a sort of pipe to `in_avail()`?

Comment: `iss.rdbuf()` returns a pointer, and that's how you dereference it and call its `in_avail` function. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access